# Passing SqlParameter[] to a method

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to make a method that execute a stored procedure whose name is a parameter of the method, and the parameters (variables) of the stored procedure are provided by `SqlParameter[] param` as follows:

```
public void modifying(string method, SqlParameter[] param)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-HP5H4JL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pocket Money;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = method;
    cmd.Connection = con;

    if (param != null)
         cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This method is in the class `Modify`. Now I want to execute the stored procedure `insertItemStudents`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertItemStudents
    @name VARCHAR(50),
    @class VARCHAR(10),
    @Gender BIT,
    @BirthDate DATE,
    @PhoneNumber CHAR(11),
    @Email VARCHAR(50)
AS
    INSERT INTO Students( StudentName, Class, Gender, BirthDate, PhoneNumber, Email)
    VALUES (@name, @class, @Gender, @BirthDate, @PhoneNumber, @Email)

    RETURN 0
```

I created a form in which there are text boxes to insert the new values. But the problem is: how to pass the `SqlParameter[]` as an argument?

Comment: What _exactly_ is the problem? I guess you know how to pass arguments to a method? So do you want to know how to create the `SqlParameter` instance? Did you get any errors? Please show how you attempted to "pass the SqlParameter[] as an argument" and how it failed.

Comment: "how to pass the SqlParameter[] as an argument?"...just like you pass any other argument to a method...create the variable, populate it and then pass it in the method call. In this case the variable happens to be an array, maybe that's what's confusing you, but it's still just a single variable at the end of the day, and you can pass it from one method to another the same as any other variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
            SqlParameter[] paramCollection = new SqlParameter[1];
            SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("name", typeof(string));
            paramCollection[0] = param1;
            modifying("methodname", paramCollection);
```